# Process bytes and check for start key

Tags: performance, c, arduino

I am working with some wireless communication in Arduino. My data will be wirelessly received like so:

```
97
97
97
...
...
```

979797 is the address of the transmitter. I have written the following code to check the address first before processing the data. My main concern is speed of computation.

```
void printBuffer(const uint8_t *serialBuffer)
{
  //print contents of buffer
  for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) 
    Serial.println(serialBuffer[i]); //remove the print in binary option to decode
}

void processBytes(const uint8_t value)
{ 
  static uint8_t serialBuffer[bufferSize]; //buffer to hold values
  static unsigned int startPosition=0;

  if(startPosition < bufferSize)
  {
    serialBuffer[startPosition] = value; 
    startPosition++;
  }

  else
  {
    printBuffer(serialBuffer);
    startPosition = 0;
  }

}//end of processBytes
void loop() { 

  //check if data is available in serial buffer
  while(RX.available())
  {
    //check for start key
    address(RX.read())
    //process data
    processBytes(RX.read());
  }   
}
void address(const uint8_t value)
{
  int counter = 0;
  int newVal = value;
  while(value == 97 && counter < 3)
  {
    counter++;
    newVal = RX.read();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The data packet just has the following components: start key (979797) and 68 bytes of data. There is no termination key. Also, the transmitter transmits one byte at a time. Thus, each value received is less than 256. Hence why I am saving the data into a uint8_t[] array.

Other than the `address()` method, most of it was borrowed from [Gammon](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial). [Here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) is the reference page for the arduino commands I am using. Are there ways I can optimize this computation?

Comment: consst in address definition. Probably a typo

Comment: Could you clarify your message protocol?  What comes after the `97 97 97`?  What does a complete message look like?

Comment: (+1) @OlzhasZhumabek, sorry about that, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bugs

There are several things wrong with this function:

> ```
> void address(consst uint8_t value)
> {
>   int counter = 0;
>   int newVal = value;
>   while(value == 97 && counter < 3)
>   {
>     counter++;
>     newVal = RX.read();
>   }
> }
> ```

1. You never use the variable `newVal`, which is a mistake.  Most likely you meant the while loop to read:

   ```
   while (newVal == 97 && counter < 3)
   ```

   As it stands, your code will always read 3 extra bytes if the first is 97, even if the second byte is not 97.  You can also get rid of the `newVal` variable and just use `value`, if you change the type of `value` to make it non-`const`.
2. `const` is misspelled.
3. When you encounter a series of three `97` bytes, you actually read 4 bytes.  The first byte is already read and passed into this function.  The function then reads 3 extra bytes.  This means that the first byte of the "message" will be missing when you call `processBytes()` later on.
4. Your message protocol is unclear.  From your code, it appears that the message protocol must be `97 97 97 byte 97 97 97 byte` which is extremely wasteful.  If that is not the protocol, there are problems with how you handle the message stream.  For example, the `address()` function strips all `97`s out of the message stream, whether or not they are part of a sequence of three.  Also, if the `address()` function does not detect a sequence of three `97`s, it always discards one byte out of the message stream.  I'd need to see an example of a proper message stream in order to advise on a solution.

Comment: Those are great points. I completely failed to realize #4. I have fixed the typo and updated the question with more information regarding the message protocol. Please let me know if anything is unclear and if I should provide more information.

Comment: I have added a fix for #4. Also, I have kept the buffer size as 100 because that seemed to be an optimal time of "listening for data" vs printing that many values.

Comment: any update on this @JS1

Comment: @Christian Actually you aren't supposed to edit your question to include fixes to the code.  What you should do is submit your new code as a separate followup question, which can include a link back to this question for reference.  Once you do that, I or others can review your new code.

Comment: (+1) Sorry about that, I have rolled back the edits and created a new follow-up question. @JS1